# PayPal PayFlow pro integration in Recurly

Tags: php, paypal, recurly

I am integrating PayPal PayFlow pro in Recurly payment gateway. I have created a PayPal Flow pro test account and got details about Vendor, User, Partner details and set those in Recurly add payment gateway for PayPal PayFlow Pro. Now Recurly is in sandbox mode. Every time I am trying to PayPal Payflow Pro Configuration Test, it is showing below error:

> Invalid Payment Gateway Login. Recurly could not connect to your
>   gateway with the credentials you provided. Please double check your
>   payment gateway's login credentials and try again.

Answer (score 3):

Recurly can only connect to production gateways when in production mode. You can use the Recurly test gateway while in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - If you also run into this problem on production this documentation might help:

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/result_values_for_transaction_declines_or_errors.htm

- Invalid Processor information entered. Contact merchant bank to verify.
- "Allowed IP Address" security feature implemented. The transaction is 
  coming from an unknown IP address. For more information, refer to Allowed 
  IP Addresses.
- You are using a test (not active) account to submit a transaction to the 
  live PayPal servers. Change the URL from pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com to 
  payflowpro.paypal.com.

If you are using the allowed ip address feature you'll have to allow:

**64.74.141.***

**8.36.93.***